# Can the insertion of impurities (doping) influence optical properties of ZnS?

Tags: optics, simulations

I am currently trying to simulate a scintillator system with silver doped zinc sulfide (ZnS:Ag). To simulate the propagation of photons inside the crystal accurately, optical properties like index of refraction and attenuation length are required. On [this](http://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=ZnS&page=Debenham) site, I have found a wavelength dependent formulation of the refractive index of undoped ZnS, which would be very easy to implement. Is it accurate to use it? Or does doping the crystal distort the refractive index too much?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the refraction index will be changed, but the absorption will differ even more. [Look at similar situation](http://www.electrochemsci.org/papers/vol8/80405594.pdf).
(P.S. I'd like to add this as comment but I cant yet, cause of reputation)

Comment: +1. I am very grateful for that reference. Do you happen to have references for the refractive index? The one you gave only treated absorption and luminescence.

Comment: A don't have references for the refractive index for ZnS:Ag, I only have information (Im(n) and Re(n) or similar) for ZnS, which is evaporated in vacuum and deposited as optical thin layer.